# ViewBinding pratices

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Is there a more generic way to init this two initialization lines?

```
private var _binding: MyFragmentViewBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

Should we call every time binding

```
binding.cancelButton.setOnClickListener {  }
binding.homeButton.setOnClickListener {  }
binding.aboutButton.setOnClickListener {   }
```

Or to create class variable?

```
cancelButton = binding.cancelButton
binding.cancelButton.setOnClickListener{}
```

And, should we set `binding = null` in `adapter`?

Comment: "Is there a more generic way to init this two initialization lines?" -- there is [a binding delegate that you can use](https://github.com/Zhuinden/fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt). "Should we call every time binding" -- you could use `with (binding) { cancelButton.setOnClickListener { } ... }` to avoid repeating the `binding` reference.

Comment: You can directly call the binding class variable but Creating class variable for binding class is more convenient way than directly call binding name."cancelButton = binding.cancelButton ;cancelButton.setOnClickListener()"

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more of a personal preference. I like to do it with extension and higher-order function

```
fun <T : ViewDataBinding> Fragment.getDataBinding(layout: Int, container: ViewGroup?): T {
    val binding: T = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, layout, container, false)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    return binding
}
```

My Fragment looks like this.

```
class InviteFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentInviteBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = getDataBinding(R.layout.fragment_invite, container)
        return binding.apply {
            inviteAll.setOnClickListener(onInviteAllClick)
            // You can set as many click listener here 
            // or some initialization related to view such as
            // setting up recycler view adapter and decorators
        }.root
    }

    private val onInviteAllClick = View.OnClickListener {
        // Invite users
    }
}
```

By doing things like this your `onCreateView` will be more readable and never going to get very long.